# No such signal QTableWidget::cellChanged(int, int)

Tags: qt, qt4, signals, qtablewidget

The title describes my problem quite well.

The offending line of code:

```
connect(table, SIGNAL(cellChanged(row, 5)), this, SLOT(updateSP()));
```

I can think of no reason why that signal is not valid. I googled around, and found a couple people with the same problem, but the solutions posed there don't work.

I'm using Qt 4.5.2 on Ubuntu Karmic, g++.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Trolltech's documentation regarding cellChanged() doesn't mention any special requirements.

I'm at a loss.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: More general tag "qt" was added.

Comment: The tag is more specific.. not general. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it seems for me that you don't understand [Qt's Signals and Slots concepts.](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/signalsandslots.html) The SIGNAL & SLOT macro take an **interface**. Something like

```
connect(table, SIGNAL(cellChanged(int, int)), this, SLOT(updateSP()));
```

might work but you need to have same argument count in your slot, to make it work like you expect:

```
connect(table, SIGNAL(cellChanged(int, int)), this, SLOT(updateSP(int, int)));
```

Slot should look something like this:

```
void ClassFoo::updateSP(int row, int column)
{
  // row is the number of row that was clicked;
  // column is the number of column that was clicked;
  // Here we go! It's right place to do some actions. =)
}
```

Comment: Ahh! I saw that exact advice earlier, but now it all makes sense. Ahh to be naive. Thanks kemiisto.